# How to keep this server setup monothreaded?

Tags: java, asynchronous

I am currently develloping a java server using selector and channels from java.nio to handle a little flash chat application. I really want to make this server mono threaded so I don't have to deals with concurrency.
Here is the structure of the server :

```
server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(Config.SERV_IP, Config.SERV_PORT)); 
server.configureBlocking(false); 
selector = Selector.open();
server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT); 
while(true){
    Timer.getInstance().clearTimeOut();
    selector.select(50);
    for (Iterator<SelectionKey> i = selector.selectedKeys().iterator(); i.hasNext();){
    SelectionKey key = i.next();
    if(key.isAcceptable()){
        //Do connection stuff
    }
    if(key.isReadable()){
        //Do handling request stuff
    }
    i.remove();
}
```

You've probably noticed the `Timer.getInstance().clearTimeOut();` line, it's the cause of my troubles. The server need to execute callbacks on certains object on certains hour, that's why I created the following Interface:

```
public interface Timed {
    public void next();
}
```

Really simple, then the following class:

```
public class Timer{
    public static Timer current = null;
    private HashMap<Timed, Long> timed_list;
    private Timer(){    
        current = this;
        this.timed_list = new HashMap<Timed, Long>();
    }
    public static Timer getInstance(){
        if(current == null){
            new Timer();
        }
        return current;
    }
    public void register(Timed t, long timeout){
        long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
        this.timed_list.put(t, finishTime);
    }


    public void clearTimeOut(){
        Set<Entry<Timed, Long>> entrys = this.timed_list.entrySet();
        ArrayList<Timed> to_clear = new ArrayList<Timed>();
        for(Entry<Timed, Long> timed: entrys){
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= timed.getValue()){
                to_clear.add(timed.getKey());
            }
        }
        for(Timed t: to_clear){
            timed_list.remove(t);
            t.next();
        }
    }
}
```

The Timer class could be optimized but this is not the problem here:

As you noticed I clear the timeout in the main loop of the server.
In order to get timer working, I need to specify a delay for `selector.select()`, if I don't, the timer willonly update when the server receive an other request. unless the server receive something, the loop will be stuck on `selector.select()` if I don't specify a delay for it.

That's worked great for a while, but now I see something. due to the delay on `selector.select()`, if 2 request are received at the same time (or in a very short interval), the second request isn't handled. it's handled if I remove the delay for `selector.select()`;

I thought on placing the Timer.clearTimeOut on a dedicated thread, but the fact is that some of the object I Time does a lot of stuff on the variable that are used by the main loop, So it will force me to handle all the concurrency, a things that I prefer to avoid.

So my question is the following: With my setup, is it possible to keep the app monothreaded, remove the delay for `selector.select()` AND got the Timer class working properly (as said, if I remove the delay, the Timer only update when the server receive a request or a conenction because the loop is stuck on `selector.select()`)

I'm open to every suggestion to keep this thing working and monothreaded, I really don't want to deal with multithread for this server...

Comment: " server mono threaded so I don't have to deals with concurrency"  a) use netty as it does this and works, b) using NIO selectors etc correctly is much harder than using multi-threaded applications. Its not a quick win for you.

Comment: @PeterLawrey My app runz actualy a multithreaded server. And I got a lot of concurrency problems and discovers new over times. I'm relly bad at concurrency. That's why I relly prefer something monothread, even if, you're right, it could be much harder to deal with finally, but IMO a monothreaded server will better works with the app

Comment: I suggest you look at netty with a thread pool of 1. This will save you from the complexities of getting NIO right.

Comment: If you're using a timer you're multi-threaded. If you want to remain mono-threaded you need to get rid of the timer and do whatever it's supposed to do after a timeout on the selector.

Comment: If you're really open to any suggestion, and really want to be mono-threaded, then I suggest leaving Java entirely and switching to NodeJS.

Comment: I thank you for all the suggestions. But sadly The server need to be ready in 2 weeks and I don't have much time to code it, so recoding it all using a new library (or a new language) is a good idea, but sadly I can't do it.